# Problems with jquery hide() and show() in internet explorer 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

please try out this simple page: http://www.ynnova.it/ie9bug/tryit.html

I use jquery 1.7.1 but I think this is not a jquery problem, it seems to be a IE9 rendering problem.

It works as expected on all browsers but not on IE9 (9.0.8112.16421).

The expected behaviour is that when I click on the "Set as disposed" button, the string "Disposed on 29/8/1975" appear on the right.
In IE9 the string appears only if I, for example, resize the IE9 window.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you add this CSS, which solves most of the strange IE issues:

```
#lblDisposalDate{
    position: relative;
}
```

Tried this with the IE debugger and seems to work.

Comment: This answer tests out successfully for me in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's `.toggle()` method in place of the `.show()` and `.hide()` methods worked for me in IE9.

There's a working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h78Eg/2/)